# What is the difference between ReadOnly=true and TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly") in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which I is readonly but want to postback its value. Earlier I set the code to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true">/asp:TextBox>
```

It was not working. I removed `ReadOnly="true"` and on code I put the following line a

```
txtContractStartDate.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Why did it start posting back the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `ReadOnly` property to true *includes* [the attribute being set](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,476):

```
if (ReadOnly) {
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.ReadOnly, "readonly");
}
```

However, the property also affects the postback behavior. It will only save the text in the view state when it’s [not readonly](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,250) (original code shortened):

```
private bool SaveTextViewState {
    get {
        if (TextMode == TextBoxMode.Password) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Events[EventTextChanged] != null || !IsEnabled || !Visible || (ReadOnly) || this.GetType() != typeof(TextBox)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the control also only attempts [to restore it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,640) when that’s the case:

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
    // …

    if (!ReadOnly && !current.Equals(postData, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
        Text = postData;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN](http://forums.asp.net/t/1834339.aspx?Difference%20between%20readonly%20true%20in%20aspx%20page%20and%20txtdate%20Attributes%20Add%20readonly%20true%20in%20page_load%20event%20for%20a%20textbox) forum:

> When you set the readonly property, asp.net knows you have marked the
>   control as readonly and alters the way the control behaves - it will
>   add a readonly html attribute to the rendered control and won't
>   process input on postback.  When you do it via the attributes, .net
>   simply treats it as an attribute, there is no special logic that
>   causes .net to "work out" that the attribute you have added means it
>   should alter a property of the control.  Basically
>
> ```
> txtdate.Attributes.Add("readonly", 'true');
> ```
>
> Is no different to .net than
>
> ```
> txtdate.Attributes.Add("ABC", 'DEF');
> ```
>
> Your attribute code adds the "readonly" attribute so it behaves like
>   you'd expect on the page, but as the .net ReadOnly property hasn't
>   been set, .net doesn't modify how the control behaves on postback.
>
> A similar thing happens with a textbox set to Password mode.  You can
>   set anything you want via .Text but the textbox won't render the value
>   as .net changes the way the control behaves when its mode is set to
>   Password.  You can circumvent this by adding the "value" attribute in
>   this way, and set the "value" to be the password.